# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, makefile

I am trying to `make` using `g++`. At first, I upgraded my `gcc` version by compiling the package locally, and add some environment path to my `~/.bashrc`

```
alias gcc='/home/rescape/lib/bin/gcc'
alias g++='/home/rescape/lib/bin/g++'
export CC=/home/rescape/lib/bin/gcc
export CPP=/home/rescape/lib/bin/cpp
export CXX=/home/rescape/lib/bin/c++
```

And I try `g++ -v` in terminal:

```
[rescape@iZ231twjza6Z mxnet]$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/home/rescape/lib/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/rescape/lib/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --prefix=/home/rescape/lib/
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.0 (GCC)
```

Still, When I do `make`, such error message occurs:

```
[rescape@iZ231twjza6Z mxnet]$ make
g++ -std=c++0x -DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -O3 -I./mshadow/ -I./dmlc-core/include -fPIC -Iinclude -msse3 -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDA=0 -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fopenmp  -MM -MT build/resource.o src/resource.cc >build/resource.d
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
make: *** [build/resource.o] Error 1
```

Any suggestions of how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: "add some environment path" -- That isn't what your aliases are doing. What happens when you actually modify your environment's `PATH` variable?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that you your Makefile is hardcoding`g++` as a rule instead of using `CXX`. And it's picking up the other copy of g++ you didn't know you already had installed from your PATH. Try setting your PATH as follows:  `PATH=/home/rescape/lib/bin:"$PATH"`

Comment: how about `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @selbie,Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

> [rescape@iZ231twjza6Z mxnet]$ make
>
> g++ ...

You not use `CXX` variable in your Makefile, so just replace `g++` with `CXX` in your `Makefile`. aliases works only when you enter commands in your shell, if you type `g++ something.cpp` bash execute `/home/bin/g++ something.cpp`, that's all, `bash` aliasing not help if external process (in our case make) execute `g++`