# How can I solve the error that I get on ubuntu Terminal: cppcheck: error: unrecognized command line option: "--std=c++0x"?

Tags: gcc, g++, static-methods, ubuntu-20.04, cppcheck

I am using a static docker that checks the codes of a project. ( See https://github.com/Ericsson/codechecker/blob/master/docs/usage.md for more details).

I got a C++ Project that I needed to analyse. I built the Project on eclipse and the rebuilt it using the Codechecker docker on the terminal. And the I generated a "makefile" using the "make"/ "makeall" command.

After analysing the compilation.json of the project. I got the following errors:

cppcheck: error: unrecognized command line option: "--std=c++0x".

I tried changing the configuration on eclipse, by adding on the Building configuration the "--std=c++0x" and "--std=c++11" option.
I also did the following:

[cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624357/cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c0x)

How and where can I add a configuration that lets the cppcheck recognises the line 2--std=c++0x"?

Comment: Try to update cppcheck

Comment: @underflow the cppcheck has already the newest version on ubuntu..

Answer (score 0):

I am a cppcheck developer. Sorry for late reply. Not sure what problem you have both "--std=c++0x" and "--std=c++11" works fine as far as I see. can it be reproduced on some simple test file?

These commands work fine for me:

```
echo "a=1;" > file1.cpp
cppcheck --std=c++0x file1.cpp
cppcheck --std=c++11 file1.cpp
```

Comment: Sadly it is not working. He just does not recognize the line option "--std=c++0x":
$ echo "a=1;" > file1.cpp
$ cppcheck --std=c++0x file1.cpp
cppcheck: error: unrecognized command line option: "--std=c++0x".

While --std=c++11 seems to be working:
$ cppcheck --std=c++11 file1.cpp
Checking file1.cpp ...

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I also checked the cppcheck manual and found out that the cppcheck does not have -std=c++0x as an option (see the page 14 on: http://cppcheck.net/manual.pdf

Comment: It depends on what version you use. Cppcheck 1.90 does not have "--std=c++0x". Latest cppcheck 2.10 has "--std=c++0x" although it's not documented in the manual. We don't recommend "--std=c++0x" it's just there for convenience/compatibility reasons. I don't know if an cppcheck upgrade is possible or if it would be easier to replace c++0x with c++11..